# D-brane wrapping around A-cycle and B-cycle

Tags: string-theory, branes

I have heard people use the terminology D-brane wrapping around A-cycle and B-cycle when talking about compactifications on a torus. What do A-cycle, and B-cycle means here, and how it's related to T-duality?

Comment: The first homology group of the torus is $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$, a and b are the two generators, i.e. single loops around each of the periodic dimensions.

Comment: So it simply means they are two different loops going around two independent circular paths on the torus? Not related to A(1-form), B(2-form), which we find in string theory usually?

Comment: Yep, nothing to do with gauge fields

Comment: Thank you for the answer.